# Shadow catcher visible through glass

Tags: transparency, glass, shadowcatcher

[image]

I have converted the body in the scene to shadow catcher. But it is visible through glass. I want to have the shiny appearance of glass but other than some reflections I want the glass to be transparent as rest of the image. How can I do this?

Comment: I found something that might help. https://blenderartists.org/t/shadow-catcher-and-glass/1142907/17 - Quoted post of [zanzio](https://blenderartists.org/u/zanzio):
> They added a new feature that lets you render transmissive materials as transparent when used with a transparent background:
> [![render setting transparent glass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4VzN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4VzN.png)<br>
> Just adjust the roughness threshold to match the roughness of your glass object. You might need to render this in separate layers anyway because it seems to erase its own shadow when its ca

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot. It totally works. Never realized what this option was for